# Thumbnail with Woocommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

With you alls help I was able to the desire thumbnail on the main page and product category pages. I followed Appearance > Customize > WooCommerce > Product Image.

However, on the individual product page, those actions don't apply. I am still getting cropped images. Any help with suggestions/advice would be appreciated.[enter

[image]

Comment: Did you try to regenerate thumbnails after changing image sizes? https://wordpress.org/plugins/regenerate-thumbnails/

Comment: I tried the thumbnail regenerator after you suggested. Edit it to 150 x 150 uncropped. I did not get the desired effect. It changed the thumbnails on the edit product page to show what I want, but on the page the customer sees, its still cropped.

Comment: Your product images are horizontal. So if you select 150x150 they should get cropped.

Comment: After I posted that response I thought about that and tried it at 150 x 0 and uncropped and results had not changed.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add this in your child theme’s functions.php

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_image_size_gallery_thumbnail', function( $size ) {
    return array(
        'width' => 150,
        'height' => 150,
        'crop' => 0,
    );
});
```

Comment: Glad to help. Please consider accepting the answer if this or any other works for you